# Setting Excel FitToPagesWide to "Automatic" in C# (VTSO)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

When I record a macro in excel to set the FitToPagesTall = 1 and leave FitToPagesWide as "Automatic" it sets FitToPagesWide to 0. However this errors when in c# (using VSTO).

sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide=0;

Any ideas? Tried setting to NULL to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

Found it.

Have to set to false.

```vb
sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = false;
```